# Broken remote desktop connections

Tags: windows-server-2008, remote-desktop

I'm having trouble with remote desktop connections to a Windows Server 2008 R2 from W7 and Vista clients dropping all the time with the following message:

"Because of an error in data encryption, this session will end. Please try connecting to the remote computer again." (See image [here](http://i34.tinypic.com/1g1xdz.png))

I've already disabled themes in both the clients and the server.

Does anyone know how to solve this? Is this a known problem? Fixes?

Comment: We saw this problem on-and-off on a particular Windows 2003 Terminal Server with Vista clients. Eventually we migrated everyone off the server and re-commissioned it.

Comment: I've tried that. No success. :(

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this question searching for another related question, so I'll go ahead and revive it from the dead:

This is probably caused by your NIC's drivers; there is a faulty IPv4 Large Send Offload in the drivers for certain Broadcom NICs. Disable that option on the NIC's driver settings and the issues should stop.